# struts jsp expression is not showing in javascript method

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a  button in my jsp and calling java script method onclick event
and passing java expression value. Java expression value is not passing to javascript method rather than it passes whole expression as srting.

```
JSP code:

<% int i = 10; %> 
<html:submit value="doEdit" property="method" onclick="testMethod('<%=i %>')" /> 

Java script code:
function testMethod(id)
{
 alert(id);
}
```

Output in alert box: <%=i %> but I'm expecting value 10.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSP code:

<% int i = 10; %> 
<html:submit value="doEdit" property="method" onclick="testMethod(<%=i %>)" /> 

Java script code:
function testMethod(id)
{
 alert(id);
}
```

Try Above code It will Work for You

Pass value without single quote and i am sure that you will get value in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for quick response. If I remove the single quote, looks like it is not going into java script method, I don't see alert message.